# Why does specialising the type of a monad lead to an error?

Tags: f#, monads, computation-expression

The following computation sequence works without error:

```
type Monad_1 () =
    member M.Bind (so : 'T option, bf : 'T -> 'T option) : 'T option =
        match so with
        | Some s -> bf s
        | None -> None
    member M.Delay (df : unit -> 'T) : 'T = // SEE CORRECTION 1
        df ()
    member M.Return (rv : 'T) : 'T option =
        Some rv

let test_1 () : unit =
    let m_1 = Monad_1 ()
    let cero =
        m_1 {
            let x1 = 10
            let! x2 = Some 20
            let! x3 = Some 30
            return x1 + x2 + x3}
    match cero with
    | Some cer -> printfn "%d" cer
    | None -> printfn "None"

test_1 () // Output: 60
```

Now suppose I take the same monad and specialise it to the integer type:

```
type Monad_2 () =
    member M.Bind (so : int option, bf : int -> int option) : int option =
        match so with
        | Some s -> bf s
        | None -> None
    member M.Delay (df : unit -> int) : int = // SEE CORRECTION 2
        df ()
    member M.Return (rv : int) : int option =
        Some rv

let test_2 () : unit =
    let m_2 = Monad_2 ()
    let cero =
        m_2 {
            let x1 = 10
            let! x2 = Some 20 // ERROR HERE: This expression was expected to have type int, but here has type int option
            let! x3 = Some 30
            return x1 + x2 + x3}
    match cero with
    | Some cer -> printfn "%d" cer
    | None -> printfn "None"

test_2 () // ERROR
```

Can someone please explain the failure in my understanding here?  Even hints would be helpful, in case it would take too long to write out a full explanation.

Comment: Delay's signature is incorrect. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233182.aspx

Comment: @MauricioScheffer, awesome!  If you post your comment as an answer, I will be glad to accept it.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per Mauricio Scheffer's comment above, the signature of `Delay` is incorrect.

CORRECTION 1

```
M.Delay<'T> (df : unit -> 'T option) : 'T option
```

CORRECTION 2

```
M.Delay (df : unit -> int option) : int option
```